# jquery loop to alert [object HTMLImageElement] and insert class to the last image

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to loop the [object HTMLImageElement] and insert a class name(visible) to last image.I'm trying this way

```
targetImage = jQuery(targetImage);
targetImage.addClass('gallery-image');
alert(targetImage[0].tagName);
jQuery.each(targetImage, function(key,valueObj){
                alert(key + "/" + valueObj );
                console.log('Loading ' + valueObj);  

                jQuery.each(valueObj, function(innerIndex, innerValue) {
                alert('image' + innerValue.id + ' is ' + index);
             });

           });
```

Comment: so what is not working? `targetImage.last().addClass('visible')` will add the class `visible` to the last image - there is no need to loop

Comment: Actually i'm doing magento swachimage in custom theme,but problem is when swach image loaded the zoom is not working

Comment: I want to alert these image and this syntax not working targetImage.last().addClass('visible')